# How can we save all the grep searches (using `M-x grep`) into history?

Tags: grep, history-variables

How can we save and retrieve all the grep searches that we do using `M-x grep` command into history ?

Comment: Doesn't it already? Doesn't `M-n` and `M-p` step you through that history?

Comment: Please clarify (in the question itself, not just in a comment): Do you just want to save the `grep` command that you used, or do you want to save its results. For the former (only), @NickD's comment applies.